# Is there an i18n api documentation?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Is there an existing i18n api documentation or do you know a beta example to i18n template?

Thank you in advance

Kevin

Comment: See also https://github.com/angular/i18n This seems to support Angular2 but Angular2 might provide something more integrated eventually.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the answer is, not yet. If you have a look at the beta announcement on the [AngularJS blog](http://angularjs.blogspot.it/2015/12/angular-2-beta.html), you'll see this under "What comes next". It's a shame they couldn't get this implemented for the first beta but hopefully we'll see it in the framework soon.